# SDK manager Android 2.2

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I installed the packages Android 2.1, Android 2.2 Android 4.0.3, but other than 2.1, and 4.0.3 does not see. What is the problem might be? I need to create a project for Android 2.2

Comment: it might have not installed properly.better download the sdk and reinstall it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SDK Manager

1 download the sdk http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

2 go to SDK directory,  go deep into tools directory.

3 double click android application

4 wait for a minutes, and the SDK manager will show. you can download the SDK version you need

AVD Manager

1 if you have download the SDK version you need. you can find AVD manager from "Tools" menu.

2 Follow google's [instruction](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html)

Comment: Thanks ,but i don't creat project Android 2.2 ,only  Android 2.2 Android 4.0.3

Comment: @AndroidNub what do you mean don't create project Android 2.2?

Comment: I want to create project for Android 2.2

Comment: problem is solved.Thanks